# Right to left flow direction on MasterDetailPage when the screen is wide

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms 3.1. and the app i'm working on has a MaterDetailPage as desktop and it could be use in right to left mode. In normal screen size everything is OK but when the screen of device is wide (like Tablets) the default behavior of Xamarin is to set MasterBehavior to Split and the outcome is like this:

[MasterBehavior = Split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AeCO.png)

Another option is to set MasterBehavior to Popover manually but it makes the problem even worse. The master page comes out form the right side of the screen and goes to somewhere near the left side of screen and detail page will be unreachable, like this:

[MasterBehavior = Popover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FOIB.png)

Is there a way to solve this problem or must wait until Xamarin.Forms team solve this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:
[You could try to give a specific width size in Tablets device](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/342946#Comment_342946)